# How do I submit my form to the correct url using a select box? [Rails 3]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

The url I want my form to submit to follows this pattern

```
/tournaments/:id/matches
```

In my app I can successfully build an href that goes there with this line

```
a.btn.btn-success href=url_for(controller: :tournaments, action: :matches, id: tournament.id) Button text
```

Here's my form (using slim)

```
  = form_tag({:controller => :tournaments, :action => :matches}, :method => :get) do                                                                                           
    select name="id"                                                           
      - @all_tournaments.each do |tournament|                                  
        - if tournament.id == @tournament.id                                   
          option value="#{tournament.id}" selected="selected" #{tournament.name}
        - else                                                                 
          option value="#{tournament.id}" #{tournament.name}                   
    br                                                                         
    input.btn.btn-success type='submit' value='Submit'
```

The form code correctly constructs a form with a select box.  But when I'm at this url:

```
/tournaments/4/matches
```

and submit the form with option 6 selected it sends me to this url

```
/tournaments/4/matches?utf8=%E2%9C%93&id=6
```

The id=6 is in the query portion.  What I want is for my form to submit to:

```
/tournaments/6/matches
```

How do I structure my form for this to work?

I'm running ruby 1.9.3 & rails 3.2.11.

My routes

```
resources :tournaments do
  get 'matches', :on => :member
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it is javascript's work, not rails, if you must specify the url to `/tournaments/:id/matches`

You can trigger an event while selecting tournament and modify the url of the form.

```
$(function(){
    $('select#id').change(function(){        
        $('form').attr('url', '/tournaments/'+$(this).val()+'/matches');
    });
});
```

see [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PqGuD/1/)

Or you can define a route like `get 'tournaments/matches'`. just put id to params list.